# Publishing site: Why are my pages blank but having webparts and controls in editing mode?

Tags: 2010, development, publishing-site, configuration, content-deployment

Started to look into Publishing site pages.

I have a few pages of a publisihing site filled with web parts and controls in editor that I fail to see. They are saved, checked in and published (few times).

[image: Editing the default.aspx of a publishing site]

Fig.1 Editing the default.aspx of a publishing site

[image]

Fig.2. Rendered (saved, committed in and published) default page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, but a few thoughts occur:

- An [EditModePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.editmodepanel.aspx) control could be in use so that some of the controls are only shown in edit mode. I think that's what the grey box around the first fields might represent. Have you tried filling in all the fields? Some fields might be to fill in metadata that is used elsewhere, rather than on page. (E.g. a thumbnail for use in content roll-up)
- The web parts might be closed or hidden. I forget which, but one of them hides the part from a published (but not and edit) page.
- The web parts might be set to use an Audience that you're not a part of.

Comment: Yes, exactly, they appeared after I filled controls and disappeared after I cleared them ... but in Edit mode. I thought they were for others... well, I was just playing around. Somewhat strange to me concepts of saving vs. publishing